# SQL REPLACE statement to replace some numbers not all

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to use a T-SQL REPLACE statement to replace the middle 4 numbers under the DepartmentID column....

I understand the simple way of changing one set of DepartmentID numbers I want to be able to change all middle numbers under DepartmentID

SELECT REPLACE (DepartmentID,'000701280918','000799990918') AS DepartmentID

FROM Employees

Objective Select all the employees, replace 4 middle numbers with 9999 in DepartmentID:

---4-----4-----4

0007 0128 0918

4 char to the left

4 char to the right

4 char in the middle

---

Table: Employees

First Column in Table: EmployeeID

Column: DepartmentID

000701280918

000701782662

000702220442

000702118362

000702108487

000702109473

000702033600

000702275707

---

How would I write the statement

Thank You for your assistance

Comment: Use a substring 
UPDATE YOURTABLE
SET YOURCOLUMN = replace(substring(yourcolumn, 1, 5) + '9999' + substring(9)) (idk about the "middle numbers are, just use teh substrings for the positio, i used in this case 1 to 4 and 9 to end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update YourTable
set DepartmentId = left(DepartmentId, 4) + '9999' + right(DepartmentId, 4)
```

This code would set the DepartmentId column to what is was before, except it would change the middle four numbers to all nines.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function:

```
update  YourTable
set     DepartmentId = stuff(DepartmentId, 5, 4, '9999')
```

Comment: How can I use this for each row in the column DepartmentId?

Comment: @user975828 if you don't filter out any rows with the `WHERE` clause, then the change will be applied to all rows.  That is an indescriminate `UPDATE`.